# How "currentTheta" works in this code?

Tags: javascript

In this [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg193979%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#example2) from MSDN, `currentTheta` is used even if not still defined.

```
var initialTheta = 0; 
var thetaDelta = 0.3; 
var angularLimit = 90; 
var theSquare = document.getElementById("mySquare");

theSquare.currentTheta = initialTheta;
```

How is this possible?

Comment: What would you expect to happen if you did this? `var x = {}; x.foo = 2;`

Answer (score 1):

This is how you define a new property on a JavaScript object.

In JavaScript, this property notation:

```
theSquare.currentTheta = initialTheta;
```

is equivalent to this notation:

```
theSquare["currentTheta"] = initialTheta;
```

Given that the two are identical, perhaps it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 1):

`theSquare.currentTheta` refers to a property called `currentTheta` on an object. Properties and variables are quite distinct in JavaScript, and you don’t have to declare a property to read from it or write to it; it will be created on writing if it doesn’t exist, and evaluate to `undefined` on reading if it doesn’t exist.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from [Objects and properties section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_and_properties) of MDN,

> **You can define a property by assigning it a value.** For example, let's create an object named `myCar` and give it properties named `make`, `model`, and `year` as follows:
>
> ```
> var myCar = new Object();
> myCar.make = "Ford";
> myCar.model = "Mustang";
> myCar.year = 1969;
> ```